# Nodejs Update SQL DB based on parameter from URL

Tags: sql, node.js, api, parameters, pug

Anyone able to help me out on this code .. What i expect to happen is when i hit thie URL I want it to update the DB Table with the user_name that is passed in the URL

Example: A user goes to /update/michael then I expect it to update the surname to Bloggs where the user_name is michael

```
app.get("/update/:user_name", function(req , res){
        var user_name = req.params.name;
        sql.connect(config, function() {
             const request = new sql.Request();
              request.query("UPDATE table SET surname = 'Bloggs' WHERE user_name= + 'req.params.name'", (err, recordset) => {
               res.end(JSON.stringify(recordset));
  });
  });
});
```

Comment: Use Patch method take user_name as a part of body  instead of get @dustypaws

Comment: var user_name = req.params.user_name; this is correct way to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the code please try this and let me know in comments if it's not work.

```
app.get("/update/:user_name", function(req , res){
            var user_name = req.params.user_name;
            sql.connect(config, function() {
                 const request = new sql.Request();
                  request.query("UPDATE table SET surname = 'Bloggs' WHERE user_name= '"+user_name+"'", (err, recordset) => {
                   res.end(JSON.stringify(recordset));
      });
      });
    });
```

Comment: No still no joy .. strange

Comment: 100% working .. would you mind explaining why it is working after that update please

Comment: your query formation is wrong for where clause =>WHERE user_name= + 'req.params.name'  And updated query is => WHERE user_name= '"+user_name+"' you have to use local variable user_name